# VSCode: Effect of not removing a default keybinding in keybindings.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Official documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule) specifies how to remove a default keybinding and free that keybinding for other usage by the user.

However, the documentation seems to be silent on what happens if the user does *not* remove the default keybinding and goes on to associate that keybinding for a different action/command.

What are the side-effects of inadvertently not removing the default keybinding and mapping that to something else?

Example:

In my keybindings.json, I have the following settings:

```
 { //What happens if this default keybindings are not disassociated as below?
    "key": "shift+alt+up",
    "command": "-editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+up",
    "command": "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

which firstly, disassociate "insertion of cursor above" from `ShftAltUp` and then rebind this to "copy line up". What happens if the first setting above does not exist?

I have verified that the order of these associations/disassociations within `keybindings.json` does not matter. That is, a user defined keybinding association can very well appear *before* in the `keybindings.json` the setting that disassociates that keybinding from the default action. The question here is, what if that disassociation does not happen at all. How does VSCode resolve this situation?

Comment: if the `when` clause of the user key binding catches all occasions the default key binding is NEVER tested so no need to remove it.

Comment: So, the user keybindings always override the default keybindings given the same when clause. Even if the when clauses are different, if two different keybindings (one default, and one userdefined) catch the same event, the preference is for the user defined. What if there are two user defined keybindings both of which catch the same keypresses?

Comment: the key binding that is lower in the `keybindings.json` file is tested first, the first key binding that has a `when` that is True is executed

Comment: Great. This actually resolves all questions. Essentially, one can think of all default keybindings as being on line 0 (top of the file) of the keybindings.json file.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules.  `When a key is pressed:

the rules are evaluated from bottom to top.
the first rule that matches, both the key and in terms of when, is accepted.` And `The additional keybindings.json rules are appended at runtime to the bottom of the default rules, thus allowing them to overwrite the default rules. `